# ReflectionIt pagination generates empty hrefs

Tags: asp.net-core, reflection, pagination

Asp.Net Core 2.2 using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging 3.5.0. Generated View has empty pagination hrefs. How to solve this?

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int page = 1, string sortExpression = "-LastUpdated")
{
  var qry = _context.Invoice.AsNoTracking();
  var model = await PagingList.CreateAsync(qry, 10, page, sortExpression, "-LastUpdated");
  return View(model);
}
```

View:

```
@model ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging.PagingList<Admin.Models.Person>
@using ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging
@addTagHelper *, ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging

<nav aria-label="Person navigation">
  @await this.Component.InvokeAsync("Pager", new { pagingList = this.Model })
</nav>

<table class="table table-striped">
 <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        ...
        <th>
            @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.LastUpdated)
        </th>
 </thead>
 ...
</table>
```

Generated pagination:

```
<nav aria-label="Person navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
     <li class="active">
         <a href="">1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
         <a href="">2</a>
     </li>
     ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Generated code uses glyphicon, which is not supported in Bootstrap 4. Perhaps a wrong version the package? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can for instance call the `AddPaging` method which you can use to set the `PagingOptions`. This allows you to specify which View is used for the Pager ViewComponent. By default a pager based on `Bootstrap3` is used. But there is also already a Bootstrap4 view available. Bootstrap4 doesn't support glyphs any more so if you switch to it you also have to specify alternatives for the `Up/Down` indicators used in the sortable headers of the table

```
services.AddPaging(options => {
    options.ViewName = "Bootstrap4";
    options.HtmlIndicatorDown = " <span>&darr;</span>";
    options.HtmlIndicatorUp = " <span>&uarr;</span>";
});
```

Reference : https://reflectionit.nl/blog/2017/paging-in-asp-net-core-mvc-and-entityframework-core ,check the `Customize` section .

Comment: Thanks for your help. The pagination layout is fine now, but the hrefs are still empty (<a class="page-link" href>nr</a>). Guess the standard routing and @Html.ActionLink(i.ToString(), Model.Action, Model.GetRouteValueForPage(i), new { @class = "page-link" }) don't match. Any Idea?

Comment: The generated pagination is not correct , it should have `page-item` for li element , i suggest you check the official code sample  : https://github.com/sonnemaf/ReflectionIT.Mvc.Paging/tree/master/src/SampleApp